# Input from serial port to Python3

Tags: python, c++, linux, matlab

everyone!
I get data from serial port by package.
A few package a second, like below:

```
275 242 280 263 235 179 234 236 233 195 203 190 202...
```

Aproximatelly 250 digits.
Every time diffrent amount.

My main purpose is real-time picture from this data.
I use python like below:

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 921600, timeout=2, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False) #Tried with and without the last 3 parameters, and also at 1Mbps, same happens.
ser.flushInput()
ser.flushOutput()
while true:
    data_raw = ser.readline()
    *some calculation*
```

My first question is: Is it possible to miss some package, if the rate of packages too fast(e.g ~1000 package per second)?
Or I must use pipe,like:

```
cat /dev/ttyS0 | python3 script.py
```

My second question is: What the language I must to use to avoid any losses? Matlab is enough? or maybe C++?
I use Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading from a serial port with a bit rate of 921600 bps.  Call it 100,000 characters per second, or 10µs / character.  250 characters will take at least 2.5ms to arrive - you can do a *lot* in 2.5ms.  (Incidentally, this means you can't get more than 400 packets per second - you just can't stuff the bits along the wire any faster!)

The device driver will do some buffering, so I wouldn't worry about it.